# How to delete prometheus log files? Cannot start prometheus by using systemd

Tags: logging, prometheus

I start up prometheus failed.error log info:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaubX.png)

I check prometheus log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCatz.png)
Have question:

1: How to delete these log files?
2：how to Loop write to a log files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't space available in your server. 
You can to resolve this problem of two ways:

1. Increase filesystem the mount point /var/lib/prometheus (if your filesystem is lvm);
2. Delete old logs segments in file /var/lib/prometheus (this option you can lose all informations about the old metrics)

The value default of the storage retentions is 15 days: 
You can decrease this value if you don't have storage available:

`--storage.tsdb.retention.time`

Or you can set retention by bytes, the value default is 0 (disabled)

`--storage.tsdb.retention.size:`

More information about storage: 
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/

Comment: Thank you reply!